# Was there ever a cartoon about Super Powered Snails?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, super-hero

No, not the CGI movie **Turbo,** but an early 90s cartoon similar to the Ninja Turtles; a team of humanoid snails who fought an army of evil bugs from space. They drew power from their shells, I believe, and had different colors.

I **know** I saw this [at _least in passing] on TV as a kid growing up!

Does this ring any bells for anyone else?

Comment: [Your time was too short, Laser-Snail.](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots1140.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds alot like [Snailiens - Supersonic Shell Fighters](http://www.agebrands.com/Snailiens.html)
They were humanoid snails that fought alien ticks. Unfortunately they never had any cartoon, but their [commercial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZPzH6FOaYk) had animated elements that might be what you remember.

Comment: Yep, that looks like it. Same Theme tune and all. I must have popped in and remember the cartoon looking cooler than the toy. It's appreciated.